# How Customise NOP Commerce eWayHosted Plugin For Other Payment Gateway

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, nopcommerce

I want to customize nopCommerce `eWayHosted` plugin for other payment gateway(Easy Pay).  I change the payment URL and the parameters.

```
public void PostProcessPayment(PostProcessPaymentRequest postProcessPaymentRequest)
{

    var strPost = "storeId=" + _eWayHostedPaymentSettings.CustomerId;
    strPost += Format("amount", postProcessPaymentRequest.Order.OrderTotal.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    strPost += Format("orderRefNum", postProcessPaymentRequest.Order.Id.ToString());

    strPost += Format("postBackURL", "http://www.smmotors.org/onepagecheckout");

    var url = _eWayHostedPaymentSettings.PaymentPage + "?" + strPost;

    var objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

    var objRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    objRequest1.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

    var objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
```

At this point 
The `Easypay` server sends back a parameter named `auth_token` to the `postbackURL` which is sent as a GET parameter.

But `Var objResponse` cannot get `auth_token` & `postBackURL`. Whats The Reason & solution

```
    //get the response from the transaction generate page
    string resultXml;

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))        
    {
        resultXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        // Close and clean up the StreamReader
        sr.Close();
    }

    //parse the result message
    var resultObj = ParseRequestResults(resultXml);

    if (resultObj.Result)
    {
        //redirect the user to the payment page
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(resultObj.Uri);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NopException(resultObj.Error);
    }
}
```

> **Below Is The Plug-in Integration Steps:**

Following process will be followed by merchants to embed the `Easypay` Plug-in in their stores:

• Merchant acquires an account through `Easypay` agents. A Welcome email containing unique Store ID and URL is sent to the Merchant after successful registration.

• Merchant logins the Easy Pay portal and access ‘Guide to Integration’ menu where Merchant is presented with step by step instructions to integrate the `Easypay` plug- in to their shopping cart/online retail shop.

Following is the sample of flow merchant should find after logging into the `Easypay` portal.

Merchants having unique store ID embed `Easypay` plug-in on checkout page of their online stores/ websites. This will integrate “Pay through `Easypay` as a payment solution in their websites. The integration of `Easypay` plug-in is a simple two-step process:

1. The merchant needs to POST following parameter to the `Easypay` on the f o l l owi n g URL:

Production (Live) Environment: 
https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf 
Sandbox Environment: 
https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf

```
• amount 
• storeId 
• postBackURL 
• orderRefNum
```

After successful redirection the customer would land on the Easypay Checkout Screen where there is a form to be filled regarding the transaction information.

2. After completing the form in Step 1 the customer will be pressing the Proceed Button and lands back on the merchant website on the same URL given in postbackURL variable in the first step. This will be a confirmation screen on merchant’s website to perform a handshake between Easypay and merchant’s website. The Easypay sends back a parameter named auth_token to the postbackURL which is sent as a GET parameter. Now the merchant needs to post back following two parameters again to the following URL:

Production (Live) Environment: 
https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf 
Sandbox Environment: 
https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf 
• auth_token 
• postBackURL

After this redirection the Easypay authenticates the auth_token sent by merchant with the one it has in the previous step, and upon successful authentication it will make customer land on the successful checkout screen sending back following two variables to the second postBackURL: 
• status 
• desc 
• orderRefNumber

Sample Code Snippet for .NET

For the first redirection:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(); 
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("storeId", "43")); 
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("amount", "10"));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("postBackURL", "http://www.my.onlinestore.com/transaction/MessageHandler"));

values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("orderRefNum", "1101")); 

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf", content); var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
```

For the second redirection:

```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("auth_token", Request.Querystring["auth_token"])); values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("postBackURL", "http://www.my.online-
store.com/transaction/MessageHandler1"));
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf", content); var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   }
```